# Can't install Ubuntu 18.04 desktop

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I couldn't install Ubuntu 18.04 from  a bootable USB drive. This error is being shown.

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi: Not Found
Failed to start MokManager: Not Found
Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed
```

I tried to do a system recovery of Windows 10 three times until now, but I still can't install Ubuntu. The same error is being shown.

Comment: Thanks Tessil, but to be true i didn't understand a bit. Can u walk me through it please? About what & how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your Motherboard seems to be in secure Boot EFI Mode:
1. If this is a parallel Installation Attempt to an existing EFI-booted OS u need to work the EFI-Boot-Functionality into your Stick Image: create the missing EFI-Folders manually and put the Setup-File (.efi) in.
2. go into your UEFI/BIOS and/or select the proper Boot-Device in the appropiate Mode: Your Stick should show up twice (EFI & without), this determines where the Installation-Routine is looking for the Setup-File: in /Boot for "normal" Installation and in /Boot/EFI for the "secure Boot" (signed) Installation.
(3.) as a workaround "secure Boot" can be disabled in the UEFI/BIOS

Comment: Legacy/CSM can also de disabled in UEFI. That guarantees the USB will boot in the proper mode, if available. Correctly done it should boot in both modes. The usual mistake is when done with Rufus with the default settings, the result is a stick that boots in Legacy only. User's must select the options UEFI/GPT.